# Redirect in php or htaccess from incoming url

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla3.4

I am new to this forum and I have a pretty straight forward question.
I have a site www.mysite.com that is the main site with all content.
Upon this I have like 20 different domains and now I would like to add domain pointers so all these domains points to the main site. I know how to do this but I would like to define somewhere in the root catalog of the www.mysite.com where these domains shall be redirected to.
For example:

```
domainA.com -> mysite.com/lures
domainB.com -> mysite.com/bait/worms
domainC.com -> mysite.com
domainD.com -> mysite.com/lines/braids
etc....
```

Is this best done in htaccess file or in a php file or in the index.php file?
I am using Joomla 3.x for all my sites.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd go with .htaccess / vhost as it's technically 'earlier' in the stack, and would require less resources.

Comment: When you go to `domainA.com` what do you want the url to be ? Still `domainA.com` or `domainA.com/lures` or redirect to `mysite.com/lures` ?

Comment: As you se above when domainA is used it shoud be redirected to mysite.com/lures

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess file for this.

It will be something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   domainA.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://example.com/lures
```

This should work.

Also you can do external redirect (http://example.com/lures) or internal redirect where user will still see domainA.com in a browser but , http://example.com/lures page is visible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the best solution, as I am a newbie when it comes to this kid of coding how do I set up multiple domains, like this?

```
    RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainA.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) example.com/lures 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainB.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) example.com/bait/worms 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainC.com 
RewriteRule ^/(.*) example.com
```

Comment: didn't get it working by this .htaccess way of doing it.